# Array is empty after filling it in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm dealing with a JSON response that is coming from an API. The `ResponseJson` contains information about a category; the `responseJson.name` contains a category name (tested in the console). Now I want to add all category names and store them in the empty array, `categoryNames`. After the for loop, the `categoryNames` turns out to be empty when I try to print it in the console, and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Here is the code:

```
_getCategories = item => {
    const categoryNames = [];
    for (let category of item.categories) {
      fetch('http://54.168.73.151/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/' + category)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          var categoryName = responseJson.name;
          categoryNames.push(categoryName);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            isError: true,
          });
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
    console.log(categoryNames);
  };
```

This questions has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question, but the answers are the other question is about a $ajax call, while I am trying to use pure JavaScript. Are there any solutions with this syntax?

Comment: This is async call and you should wait after all "fetch" calls are completed then categoryNames should contain all the name

Comment: While the duplicate question uses a different syntax, the fundamentals are the same - `fetch` is async, and the for-loop is not waiting for the response to continue. When `console.log(categoryNames)` is called, none of your responses have completed, so the array remains empty. Instead of doing a for-loop, you can follow one of many examples for [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), or awaiting a series of async calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
_getCategories = item => {
  const categoryNames = [];
  let  fetches = [];
  for (let category of item.categories) {
    fetches.push(fetch('http://54.168.73.151/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/' + category));
  }

  Promise.all(fetches).then(res => {
    /* do your stuff here */
  })
};
```

You should you Promise.all to wait all fetches are done.
Can you try above code?

Comment: I've been trying this solution, but the array still turns out to be empty at the end. I used the line `categoryNames.push(res.name);` in the `Promise.All(fetches)`, and try to print the array after that.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: `_getCategories = item => {
    const categoryNames = [];
    let fetches = [];
    for (let category of item.categories) {
      fetches.push(
        fetch('http://54.168.73.151/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/' + category)
      );
    }
    Promise.all(fetches).then(res => {
      categoryNames.push(res.name);
    });
    console.log(categoryNames);
  };`

Comment: @MJM well, you should console log the res inside the callback. Because the Promise is async and it executes after the console.log(categoryNames);

Comment: 'res' does not contain the data I need, only headers and information about the call.